# make dropdown item as selected in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have make a demo of angularj dropdown menu,and its working fine,But now i want to make selected item as active,I dont have any idea how to do this,can anybuddy please help me ,I have used [Angular-Dropdown.js](https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns/tree/master/dist)

Mycode is as below:

**html**

```
<span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" style="border: none; padding: 0">
                <i  class="ion-android-more-vertical" dropdown-disabled="isDropdownDisabled" style="font-size: 26px; margin: 0; padding: 0 17px 0 12px;" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" dropdown-disabled="dropdownsDisabled"></i>  
            </span>
```

**js**

```
  $scope.ddMenuOptions = [
        {
            text: 'Featured',
            code: 'F'
        }, {
            text: 'Name (A-Z)',
            code: 'A'
        }, {
            text: 'Rating',
            code: 'M'
        }, {
            text: ' Most Popular',
            code: 'MP'
        }
    ];

    $scope.ddMenuSelected = {
    };



    $scope.$watch("ddMenuSelected", function(newValue, oldValue) {

        $scope.selectedItem = newValue;
        var result = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
        var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);
        wrappedResult.removeClass('active');
        wrappedResult.addClass('activated');
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {

            console.log("=========" + $scope.ddMenuSelected.code);
            $rootScope.ddMenuOptions = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set divider to true/false

example:

```
$scope.ddSelectOptions[0].divider = false;
```

or

```
$scope.ddSelectOptions[1].divider = true;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/66mrssb7/7/

Comment: tried your code inside $watch but nothing is happening.

Comment: I made a simple example. It can exactly choice the specified option.
https://jsfiddle.net/66mrssb7/

Comment: Oh,Thanks frend,but its not what i need,I want to make option as **active** when i again open dropdown,just same as you have made **label* as active in your example,(active seems it should display different than other items).you get my question dear?please help me.

Comment: You can set "divider" to true/false.
$scope.ddSelectOptions[1].divider = true;
$scope.ddSelectOptions[0].divider = false;
is that what you want?
https://jsfiddle.net/66mrssb7/5/

Comment: Exaclty great,but how to do this on dropdown selection,i mean where to write down this code is the problem..:(

Comment: watch it. https://jsfiddle.net/66mrssb7/7/
this directive has a change event. but it invoke before changed.
<div dropdown-select="ddSelectOptions" dropdown-model="ddSelectSelected" dropdown-disabled="dropdownsDisabled" dropdown-onchange="change()"></div>

Comment: Can you help in me in my one more query dear?

Comment: sure. or you can post a new question.

Comment: this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750805/refresh-previous-page-in-onsen-ui-on-back-button